# Functions not being called within other functions in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a task to create an "adventure" game imitating a flowchart.

It is based on opening two Russian Dolls, a green one which has a key to open the blue one. The first functions selects a user input between Doll 1 or Doll 2 and will either forward the user to the second function or restart the option presented in the first method.

My problem is that when I am calling these functions (choice() or choice2()) within themselves they are displaying errors.

```
class main:

  global key
  key = False

  def choice2():
    if (key == True):
      print("Congratulations, you have found the golden token.")
    else:
      print("Find the key first")
      choice()

  def choice():
    c1 = input("1. Blue Doll or 2. Green Doll?")

    if (c1 == 2):
      print("The doll contains a small key. You take the key")
      key = True
      choice()

    elif (c1 == 2):
      choice2()

  print("There is a green Russian doll and a blue Russian doll on the table.")
  choice()
```

When ran, it shows the initial question (There is a blue/green doll which one do you want to open) and when I type 1 the code breaks and stops instead of going to the next part. When I enter 2 this is the error I'm getting (coding on repl.it)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    class russianDoll:
  File "main.py", line 25, in russianDoll
    choice()
  File "main.py", line 22, in choice
    choice2()
NameError: global name 'choice2' is not defined
```

Comment: You seem to have put all your functions inside a class but are still trying to use them as standalone functions. Perhaps you should lose the class, since it does not serve any clear purpose.

Comment: This isn't Java. You don't need to stuff everything into a class.

Comment: `choice2` isn't a global; it's a class attribute. It can only be accessed via `main` or an instance of `main`.

Comment: @chepner: And because they're running the methods while defining the class, `main` doesn't actually exist yet; they can't call `choice2` at all except at top-level like they did with `choice`.

Comment: As a former Java programmer, this gotcha always catches me.  Both need to be marked @staticmethod and both need to be called as main.choice(), main.choice2(), even with main.

Comment: If you'll replace class definition with function, you could use `nonlocal` in your inner functions. E.g. `nonlocal choice` at the beginning of the `choise2()`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You could if you added `choice` and `choice2` to the `global` statement, though that doesn't mean this is even remotely a good design for a program.

Comment: @chepner, I'd rather use `nonlocal` to not move those functions to global scope

Comment: @chepner: Huh. TIL that `global` works in class definition context, not just in function context. Not that I can think of many sane reasons to do it (as in this case, where it's a terrible idea), but apparently there are still things I don't know about Python besides the intricacies of `asyncio`. Thanks for that! :-)

Comment: Also, the mutual recursion is a bad idea since Python doesn't do tail-call optimization. To even trigger that issue, though, you need to use `c1 = int(c1)` to ensure either condition can be true.

Comment: @OlvinRoght: `nonlocal` doesn't work in this case; it'll die with `SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'b' found`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, firt of all I see no `b` in code. And [it will work](https://repl.it/repls/HungryIncredibleLogin).

Comment: @OlvinRoght in the code here, `nonlocal` in `choice` refers to the global scope, just like `global`, because a `class` statement doesn't create a new scope. `nonlocal` outside a method, directly in the body of the `class` statement, produces a syntax error.

Comment: @chepner, this class should be a function.

Comment: @OlvinRoght: Yeah, `b` was an arbitrary name I used to test. It doesn't work in a class is the point, as chepner points out.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I still think that he(*she?*) defined class mistakenly, it should be a function.

Comment: Additionally, in choice the statement c1 = input(". . .") yields a str result, therefore the test if (c1 == 2) will never repass, since you are comparing a str to an int.